# how can i enable ckeditor by button click in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-4.5, ckeditor.net

i have used  ckeditor.net dll in my asp.net project.

in one of my pages with master page , i have used ckeditor:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" AutoGrowMinHeight="120"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Then,i have set on all child of NewsDetail div to 'disabled' by this code in jquery:

```
$("Div#NewsDetail").find("*").attr('disabled', true);
```

by this code, ckeditor is disabled too.
my problem is that , when i try to remove disabled attribute by below code, ckeditor does not enabled again:

```
$("Div#NewsDetail").find("*").removeAttr('disabled');
```

how can i enable it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery 1.6+, the it would be better to use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.removeProp](http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/)..

Instead of removing the attribute, try changing the attribute value like

```
$("Div#NewsDetail").find("*").prop('disabled', false);
```